# Hibernate retrieve results from database based on condition

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am a bit lost when it comes to retrieving results from the database.

My `MemberModel` consists of 4 fields: `id`, `username`, `password` and `email`. I have been able to successfully save it to database.

Now I need to retrieve an `id` of a member who's `username` equals "Test".

I tried something along the lines:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = :username");
query.setString("username", username);
List<MemberModel> returnedMembers = query.list();
MemberModel member = returnedMembers.get(0);
int id = member.getId();
```

However I get an error that `member.getId()` cannot be converted to int, since it is `MemberModel`... But the getter `getId()` returns `int`.

I am quite confused. The question is: what would be the easiest and fastes way to retrieve member `id` based on condition (value of `username`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your code into something like this:

```
public MemberModel getMember(String username) {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from  " + MemberModel.class.getName() + " where username = :username ");
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    return (MemberModel) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
MemberModel model = someInstance.getMember("someUsername");
int id = model.getId();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a native SQL query, but should use [HQL query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String%29). That means you have to change the query to:

```
session.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MemberModel m WHERE m.username = :username")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use criteria and restrictions api.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MemberModel.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
MemberModel member=(MemberModel)criteria.uniqueResult();
```